# How to add a "yellow diamond" while editing points of a shape?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In MS PowerPoint I am able to change some shapes by using the yellow diamond or by right-clicking on the shape and then selecting editing points. I would like to do the later and add a point that will appear as a yellow diamond later. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, unfortunately.